# Reference by value in integer is override my linq query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

Do you know why this reference by val does the share choice ID  in this query ?

Here is the code:

```
lst = new List<IQueryable<tblProduct>>();
int choiceID = 30;
lst.Add(from t in originalQuery
    where t.tblProductChoiceTag.Any(c => c.ChoiceID == choiceID)
    select t);
choiceID = 31;
lst.Add(from t in originalQuery
    where t.tblProductChoiceTag.Any(c => c.ChoiceID == choiceID)
    select t);

IQueryable<tblProduct> q = null;

bool first = true;
foreach (var tquery in lst)
{
    if (first)
    {
        q = tquery;
        first = false;
    }
    else
    {   //the next one combine it
        q = q.Union(tquery);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've captured the `choiceID` variable. Remember that (a) query executions are deferred and (b) closures capture the variable, not the value. In your case, you'll basically want to use a different variable for each query or simply code in the number the variable is representing.